# Does Qt support 'Open a folder and highlight a particular file'?

Tags: qt, pyqt, qt4, pyqt4, pyqt5

Does Qt provides a means of 'Open a folder and highlight a particular file'? I found a solution [Open a folder and highlight a particular file with WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169942/open-a-folder-and-highlight-a-particular-file-with-wpf), but it's only for Windows. Does Qt provide a universal solution?

After doing a file search, I would like to show the file location hyperlinks in `QTextBrowser`. Let users click on the links to locate the file in a file manager (not open them). I'm not so sure if this feature is aslo available for iOS or Linux.

Comment: No, Qt doesn't, because it is a platform-specific feature. You need to use WinAPI. Btw, for some stuff there are special classes: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwinextras-module.html

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13680415/how-to-open-explorer-with-a-specific-file-selected

Comment: Minion, can you clarify exactly what you mean? Your question sounds like it needs a file-select dialog box but others have questioned that.

Comment: I'm talking about common function in Windows, such as 'locate the file', 'explore here'. I have clarified this in my question.

Comment: There is no such feature in iOS or Linux? Do any body know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. What you are trying to do is platform-specific (i.e. instruct the native file browser to open and perform some specific action) and therefore not supported.

Qt does have platform-specific features, but they largely are focused on *enabling* platform-specific interaction (like getting a native OS X menu handle) rather than *integrating* platform-specific behavior. Yes, pretty much all platforms have some form of file browser, but they also have lots of APIs, quirks, and features not available elsewhere. Qt does its best to balance being feature-rich without binding too tightly to the platform.

The closest you can come is with [`QDesktopServices::openUrl`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdesktopservices.html#openUrl), but that just opens the directory. Check out [`QProcess::execute`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#execute) to call the native file browser along with command-line arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. [QFileDialog](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html) is the class you are looking for.

In python it could look like this:

```
QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, "Choose a path and filename", os.getcwd().replace("\\", "/") +
                                  "/data/highlighted_file.txt", filter="Text Files (*.txt)")
```

The `os.getcwd().replace("\\", "/")` part merely selects your current folder and replaces the backslashes with forward slashes.

Edit: It seems like I misinterpreted your initial question. The other answer by [@Jon Harper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37806836/5528308) is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: `QDir::toNativeSeparators` / `QDir::fromNativeSeparators`

Comment: Qfilsytemmodel with qtreeview